# Difference between using thresholds to classify and using a custom objective function

Tags: classification, precision-recall, threshold, log-loss

Suppose we are faced with a binary classification problem. The standard approach seems to be to fit a probability estimator using a loss function like log loss and then afterwards determine the optimal classifier score threshold to minimise our expected misclassification costs (if the costs of false positives are different from false negatives).

An alternative approach might be to implement a custom loss function for instance by modifying log loss from:

$$
\text{log loss} = - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i}^N y_i log(p_i) + (1-y_i)log(1-p_i)
$$
where $N$ is the number of samples, $y_i$ is 1 if sample i is a positive case and 0 otherwise and $p_i$ is the estimated probability that sample i is a positive case to:
$$
\text{cost sensitive log loss} = - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i} A \cdot y_i log(p_i) + (1-y_i)log(1-p_i)
$$
where A is a measure of how much more costly a false negative is than a false positive. Then after training this new probability estimator you could simply assign a sample to the positive class if $p_i > 0.5 $ without needing to determine a threshold.

My question is, are these two approaches identical? If not, in what ways are they different? What are the tradeoffs between them?

Comment: The misclassification loss is not a proper loss function.  And the first part of your analysis doesn't use a classifier in any correct sense of the word, but instead is using a probability estimator.  Stick with a proper scoring rule with the probability estimates as discussed [here](http://fharrell.com/class-damage).  Also see [this](http://fharrell.com/post/classification).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've modified it to (hopefully) be using ther terms classifier and probability estimator correctly. Your first link gives me a 404 but I assume it should point [here](http://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/)? 

Your points are well taken but suppose we are in a situation where we do know all the utilities, would the two approaches then be equivalent? I **think** the second one is proper but for a different probability, something like "what is the probability that the cost will be lower if I assign this case to positive rather than negative"?

Comment: Yes sorry - link should be http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage . To your  question, the likelihood function is **the** objective function, and utilities should in no way modify parameter estimates.  Utilities (loss function) are applied at the decision point to actualize the point estimates.  So get the best predicted probabilities you can, then plug in utilities.